# Variation of interval partitioning

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I have a variation of the interval partitioning problem (given a set of lectures with start and finish times s and f, find the least number of classrooms needed to schedule them so that no two overlapping lectures coincide in the same classroom), the variation is that there are two lectures say A and B that cannot coincide regardless of their compatibility.
I have an idea which is to first put the maximum number of compatible classrooms except B with A, and the solve the original problem with the remainder(including B), this creates a compatible assignment but i can't figure out how to prove it's optimal.